# Unmarshalling JPA entity using JAXB

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink

I'm having trouble in my JAX-RS service unmarshalling a JSON string back into my JPA entity with JAXB.  Marshalling works and I get the following JSON string from the service:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "items":[{
        "id":{"pairName":"PAIR-1","eventId":1},
        "pair":{"name":"PAIR-1","val":1.0},"quantity":2}
    ]}
}
```

However, sending this string back to my service gives an error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column EVENT_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: -1
Call: INSERT INTO ITEM (QUANTITY, EVENT_ID, PAIR_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?) bind => [2, null, PAIR-1]
```

EVENT_ID is in the string, how do I get the object back?  I'm using Java EE 5, JPA 1.0 with Jersey and EclipseLink.

JPA Entities

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Event implements Serializable {    
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "event")
    private List<Item> items;           
}

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemPk id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Pair pair;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID")
    @XmlTransient
    private Event event;

    private int quantity;
}

@Embeddable
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItemPk implements Serializable {   
    @Column(name="PAIR_NAME", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String pairName;

    @Column(name="EVENT_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private long eventId;
}

@Entity
public class Pair implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    private String name;

    private float val;
}
```

JAX-RS service

```
@Path("/events")
public class EventService {

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Event> list() {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("service");
        }
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Event.findAll");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void update(Event event) {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("service");
        }
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(event);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `ItemPk.eventId` is `insertable=false, updatable=false`, so JPA does not try to insert this field. Instead it tries to insert the field `Item.event` as SQL `EVENT_ID`. **BUT** the `Item.event` is `@XmlTransient`, thus *not read* from the JSON, thus `null`.

Maybe you should set `insertable=false, updatable=false` to the relations in `Item` (fields `pair` and `event`) and let the fields of the primary key (`ItemPk`) be insertable and updateable.

(I get the feeling that this will cause other problems, so some extra tweaking will be required.)